# python regex and replace

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to learn python and regex at the same time and I am having some trouble in finding how to match till end of string and make a replacement on the fly.

So, I have a string like so:

```
ss="this_is_my_awesome_string/mysuperid=687y98jhAlsji"
```

What I'd want is to first find `687y98jhAlsji` (I do not know this content before hand) and then replace it to `myreplacedstuff` like so:

```
ss="this_is_my_awesome_string/mysuperid=myreplacedstuff"
```

Ideally, I'd want to do a `regex and replace` by first finding the contents after `mysuperid=` (till the end of string) and then perform a `.replace` or `.sub` if this makes sense.

I would appreciate any guidance on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 re.sub(r'[^=]+$', 'myreplacedstuff', ss)
```

The idea is to use a character class that exclude the delimiter (here `=`) and to anchor the pattern with `$`

explanation:

`[^=]` is a character class and means *all characters that are not `=`*
   `[^=]+` one or more characters from this class
   `$`  end of the string

Since the regex engine works from the left to the right, only characters that are not an `=` at the end of the string are matched.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. So, does the `+$` look for end of string?

Comment: No only `$`, `+` is quantifier for `[^=]` that mean 1 or more times, I will edit a more detailed explanation soon.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed explanation - I have certainly learnt here. Accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> mymatch = re.search(r'mysuperid=(.*)', ss)
>>> ss.replace(mymatch.group(1), 'replacing_stuff')
'this_is_my_awesome_string/mysuperid=replacing_stuff'
```

You should probably use @Casimir's answer though. It looks cleaner, and I'm not that good at regex :p.

Comment: thanks so much for the alternative solution. I agree, Casimirs answer is a clean one liner. I agree - I am trying to be good with regex! I am quite bad at this!

Comment: @JamesW Well, you aren't alone :)

Comment: you should read more about regexps on sites like [courses on the MIT](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-045j-automata-computability-and-complexity-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_045JS11_lec04.pdf) and also practice on [tutorial sites](http://regexone.com/). I think it helps a lot to understand that Regexps are "simply" automata with cabalistical characters. In the end, it's expression is far less sophisticated than most programming language.. but the paradox is that it is harder to learn :-)